# 'unknown variable "character-set-server=utf-8"' error at mysqldump

Tags: debian, mysql

I'm using mysql 5.5.38 at SMP Debian Linux 3.2.60.

It works fine, but I'm unable to do any backup. mysqldump always shows 'unknown variable "character-set-server=utf-8"'  error. i.e.

> $ mysqldump --version
>
> unknown variable "character-set-server=utf-8"

Is there any way to fix it in my.cnf or any other way?

Answer (score 2):

Per documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-applications.html ,

```
[mysqld]
character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

change `character-set-server=utf-8` to `character-set-server=utf8` in your `my.cnf` file

Comment: I don't agree with this solution for two reasons: 1) the message says that the variable is unknown, not the value... and 2) I got the error with `utf8` in the first place, not `utf-8`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Edit my.ini for the targetted server
2. Search for `[mysqldump]` section.
3. Replace `character-set-server=utf8` or `character-set-server=utf8`, whichever you have, with `default-character-set=utf8`
4. Restart MySQL server.

Answer (score -3):

You have the line:

```
character-set-server=utf-8
```

in your `~/.my.cnf` or the system-wide `my.cnf`. This variable isn't recognized and causes an error, so you should remove it.